# What Subversion authorization scenario

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I need to setup & maintain easily many Subversion repositories and make each of them accessible for strictly specified list of users only. 
No anyonymous checkout (no read access).
What authorization scenario should I use here

Answer (score 0):

you can use subversion through ssh (svn+ssh://) with unix based access privileges.

1. Create users on your subversion server (adduser)
2. Create user groups (groupadd) and add users to groups
3. Create svn projects
4. chgrp -R accessgroup1 svnproject1, ...
5. chmod -R g+rwx svnproject1

Thats about it. I hope I was clear enough.